# Windows 7 compatibility with oracle sql developer version 1.5.5.59?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am currently using Oracle sql developer version 1.5.5.59, in some time my O.S. is going to migrate from WinXP to Windows 7 [64 bit] can anyone suggest me how to check/find whether Oracle version 1.5.5.59 need to be upgrade or not?

Thanks

Comment: Why such an old version? I would have thought this would be more affected by the Java version you have available, rather than the OS itself; but you probably need to ask about this on the [SQL Developer forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked Oracle sql developer 1.5.5.59 is compatible with Win 7 [64 bit]